# Is it better to add a youtube link or to download and link the video file on the website in terms of performance?

Tags: html, performance, dom, github-pages, mod-pagespeed

I just want to know if the page will load faster with the youtube embed link or with a link to the video file hosted using a free platform like github pages?

Comment: I would guess the YouTube embed link but if you are just talking about load-time it may be different.

Comment: You can try and measure! Beware copyrights!

Comment: Thanks @Ucho , actually I tried it already and found that the performance of embedded videos is much better (at least 5x faster) as compared to yt links. No doubt that they have very good servers and highly optimized scripts running online but they get millions of requests every second, so they can't load a video faster than embedded video loaded using github servers. Also, embedded videos provide a lot of control on the video. And all the videos are made by me only so no chance of any copyright issues :)